# How do I install fay?

Tags: javascript, haskell, cabal, fay

I'm running ubuntu 13.10 and I'm having trouble installing fay. I installed haskell using  `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform` . I try `cabal install fay` and I receive the following message:

```
$ cabal install fay
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring type-eq-0.4.2...
cabal: The program cpphs is required but it could not be found.
Failed to install type-eq-0.4.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
fay-0.20.0.0 depends on type-eq-0.4.2 which failed to install.
haskell-names-0.3.3.2 depends on type-eq-0.4.2 which failed to install.
type-eq-0.4.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I tried install `cpphs`, but I already have it.

```
$ cabal install cpphs
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
cpphs-1.18.4
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

Finally, I tried installing `type-eq` by itself, and expectedly it is dependent on `cpphs`.

```
$ cabal install type-eq
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring type-eq-0.4.2...
cabal: The program cpphs is required but it could not be found.
Failed to install type-eq-0.4.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
type-eq-0.4.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What is the output of `which cpphs`?

Comment: I got <code>cpphs not found</code>

Comment: I think you need to add `~/.cabal/bin` to `PATH`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to comments of the original post:

1. `cabal` complains that cannot find already installed `cpphs`
2. `which cpphs` says command cannot be found
3. which means `cpphs` does not in the search paths of shell
4. add `~/.cabal/bin` to `PATH` can be used to fix this problem